# Topology rule for geometry in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: geometry, arcgis-pro, topology

Is there anyway to write topology rule for the polygon geometry?

I want nice rectangle, without any self-crossing lines. But sometimes I found those. So I want to use topology. I am adding an pic with bad example.

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

Comment: what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: You don't need a topology rule to enforce geometry integrity.  If you Repair Geometry, or use `arcpy.Geometry`, it's possible that "bowties" will be "repaired" into two touching triangle parts, not the quadrilateral that was intended.

Comment: So what You suggesting to use, to get those quadriteral shapes ? Is it even possible ?